# What is Half-Inverse-Student-t distribution?

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

In the paper of [Vanhatalo et al 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02432), section 5.3 page 15, they use Half-Inverse-Student-t distribution as a prior:

[image]

I have never heard of such distribution and I have problems finding it. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_\nu$ have the central $t_\nu$ distribution, then the Half-Inverse-t must be the distribution of $| 1/T |$, where $|\cdot|$ is the absolute value.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded-t_and_half-t_distributions.

Plot of the density with some simulations:

[image: histogram of simulated values with overlaid density]

Note that while the $t$ distribution have heavier tail with small df, the opposite is the case for the inverse-$t$ and half-inverse-$t$.

Code for simulation and plot (R):

```r
N <- 1000000
nu <- 4
set.seed(7*11*13) # My public seed

x <- 1/abs( rt(N, nu) )

# The inverse-half-t density: 

dinvhalft <- function(x, nu=1) 2*dt(1/x, nu)*(1/x)^2 

hist(x, breaks="FD", prob=TRUE, xlim=c(0, 15), main="Simulation from dinvhalft,  df=4", ylim=c(0, 0.55), col="skyblue")
plot(function(x)dinvhalft(x, nu=4), from=0, to=15, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

The question also asks for the half-$t$
 distribution. That is simpler, if $T$ have a $t_\nu$-distribution with density $f_\nu$, then the half-$t$ distribution is the distribution of $|T|$. It will have density (by symmetry about 0) given by $f_{\text{half-$t_\nu$}}(x)= 2 f_\nu(x)\cdot \mathcal{I}(x \ge 0)$, which can be coded in R as

```r
dhalft <- function(x,nu) ifelse(x >= 0, 2*dt(x,nu), 0)
```

Comment: thank you kjetil, but in the half-t, zero is a legitimate value (with the highest density actually), but the inverse of zero is not a number... isn't this a problem?

Comment: No, densities at both 0 and $\infty$ are zero ...

Comment: density of **half-t** at 0 is *not* zero, please re-read my comment...

Comment: Are you sure? The function (in the new edit) gives me `dinvhalft(1E-12, nu=4)` with result
 `[1] 2.4e-35`. By continuity the density at zero is zero. Try to plot the density only close to zero.

Comment: but in the comment I was talking about half-t, not inverse-half-t.... half-t is peaking at zero.... please have look at the question in the comment, thanks! :-)

Comment: I will augment the answer!

Comment: Hi kjetil, I am not "asking for half-t distribution". I did so many attempts to explain my question in the first comment but you still seem to not understand. You keep circling around and answering things I haven't ask. I'd be happy if you just took time to carefully re-read my first comment under this answer and answered the problem which I pointed out there. Thanks.

Comment: " zero is  a legitimate value", yes, it can occur, but this is a continuous distribution, so the probability $P(T=0)=0$ and also $P(|T|=0)=0$ and zero probability events is not a problem.